# Roots of $z^5 (z − 2) = w $ in Unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification

The Q is following : 
Prove that for each w in the unit disc $D(0, 1)$, the equation $z^5 (z − 2) = w $ has exactly five solutions in the unit disc counted with multiplicity.

My Approach : let $f(z) = z^5 (z − 2) - w $ Now $w \in D(0, 1)$. I apply Rouche's Theorem on $f$ on the Disk $D(0,1)$ and thus I get $g(z) = 2z^5$ which has $5$ roots in the given Disk and hence proved.

Is this approach correct ?

Comment: Are we doing your homework?

Comment: I am trying out problems. If you wish, you could assume so... I will delete the Q.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't delete it, it seems to me a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Is my approach correct ?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The proof is correct.
$
\:\:
$